# React: Loadable is not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-loadable

Hi I am new in react and I want to implement `routing` with `Loadable`, But Its not working Its showing blank page when either **http://localhost:3000/user** or **http://localhost:3000/**

Could you please correct me where I am doing wrong.
I am also getting-

**Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `string` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.**

**My codes are:**

**home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link} from 'react-router-dom';


class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <div>
                  <h1>Welcome to the Tornadoes Website!</h1>
                  <h5><Link to="/user">User</Link></h5>
                </div>
              );
    }
} 

export default Home;
```

**user.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class User extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>6/5 @ Evergreens</li>
                    <li>6/8 vs Kickers</li>
                    <li>6/14 @ United</li>
                    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default User;
```

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { history } from './helpers/history';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import './App.css';

const Loading = () => <div> Loading... </div>;

const Home = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./components/home-component/home'),
  loading: Loading
});

const User = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./components/user-component/user'),
  loading: Loading
});

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component="Home" />
          <Route path="/user" component="User" />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'))

registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: How did you get it doesn't work?

Comment: Its showing Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `string` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.

Comment: I got from https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#route-based-code-splitting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are doing this: `<Route exact path="/" component="Home" />` which should be `<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />` since you want to use that variable, it's impossible to reference by String when he can't know which Component you want. I hope this helps

Comment: I checked with  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="user" component={User} /> but still problem is same.

Comment: Should not really pose a problem, that's how i use it and it works for me, an issue could be that your Component is not the default export since with `() => import('./components/home-component/home')` you are using the default export

Comment: @ jovi De Croock  I have exported it with export default Home; & export default User;

Comment: Yes i see that, that's why i'm saying it shouldn't pose a problem. The issue "Its showing Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop component of type string supplied to Route, expected function" you stated above will be solved with my answer. 

Try my answer and see if there's an additional error and reply with it if there is one :-) can try to help with that

Comment: While using class Home extends Component { } and class User extends Component { } the problem remains same, But when I am using export Home ; or export User; its showing error as Unexpected token, expected { (16:7) on export User;

Comment: Yes but try the solution from my answer with using `component={Home}` and tell me if that has errors. As long as you're starting with a faulty Route distribution. Hold on to the export default

Comment: I tested with <Route exact path="/" component={Home} /> <Route path="user" component={User} /> but still problem is same. nothing has been changed in output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173319/discussion-between-jovi-de-croock-and-shubham-verma).

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like there is a `isRequired` propType that you have missed when calling your component. Can you post your components here as well?

Comment: Could you explain more? Where should I put isRequired ?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma have you included PropType validation on your two components home & user?